# Wildfly disabling logging subsystem

Tags: java, logging, wildfly-9, subsystem

in my web application i need to use my logging framework. The framework is loaded by each webapplication like a jar dependency.

In order to disable jboss logging subsystem i tried to create a

```
jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

file copied in:

```
(firt try)- webapplication.war\WEB-INF\
(second try) - webapplication.war\WEB-INF\lib\my_framework.jar\META-INF\
```

the content of the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.logging (or org.jboss.logging)" /> 
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
```

But nothing seems to change in the log process.
I checked the framework MANIFEST.MF and no other dependencies are imported.

I also realized that by cancelling the logging subsystem from standalone.xml the custom logging framework works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can exclude subsystems from deployments with in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as well. Excluding the module does not exclude the subsystem from processing the deployment.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Excluding the subsystem will stop the deployment from being processed by the subsystem.